# Making a box move smoothly and slowly to a set position in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<html>
<div id="my_box_realtime" style="background-color: red; position: absolute; min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = bottom
  var y = right
  var d = document.getElementById('my_box_realtime');
  var position = 0;

  setInterval(function() {}, 500)
  position += 1;
  d.style.top = position + 'px';
  d.style.left = position + 'px';

  function my_box_realtime() {
    if (position)
  }
</script>

</html>
```

The box needs to move smoothly and slowly to a set coordinate of bottom 0 and right 0.
Any help would be great. Very new to this and it's an assignment I have.

Comment: The code is incomplete. Where do the bottom and right values come from? The `setInterval()` is empty. Maybe you want to move the below code inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, we need to:

1. maintain top & left values separately
2. Check on Every Interval if the Boxes Bottom & Right have reached the Target Distance in relation to the `window`
3. Update the Top & Left Values if necessary
4. Finally, when the Box is at the Target Location, Clear the Interval.

```js
var d = document.getElementById('my_box_realtime');
var x = 0; // Bottom Target in px
var y = 0; // Right Target in px
var positionTop = 0;
var positionLeft = 0;

let interval = setInterval(function() {
  const {
    bottom,
    right
  } = d.getBoundingClientRect();

  const clientW = window.innerWidth;
  const clientH = window.innerHeight;

  if (clientH - bottom !== x) {
    positionTop += 1;
    d.style.top = positionTop + 'px';
  }

  if (clientW - right !== y) {
    positionLeft += 1;
    d.style.left = positionLeft + 'px';
  }

  if (right === clientW && bottom === clientH) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 50);
```

```html
<div id="my_box_realtime" style="background-color: red; position: absolute; min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px"></div>
```